# Border animation on hover with a transparent section moving left to right

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions, border

I have this code trying to make an animation on hover. Something like this :

```
TextLink      hover: TextLink
--------             --  ----
```

I am trying to have an animation that looks like the "transparent" portion is moving from **left till the end of the text**.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #16263d;
}

div {
  padding: 30px;
}

a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 24px;
  transition: all 0.75s ease-in-out;
}

a span {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}

a:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
  -ms-filter: none;
  filter: none;
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

a:after {
  content: '';
  width: 35px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #16263d;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(-35px);
  transition: all 0.75s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#"><span>Text Link and something more than this</span></a>
</div>
```

The problem is that 100% of the transform transition is not taken into consideration ... seems like only 100px are.

Comment: The output of your code seems very similar to what you seem to be seeking. Can you please explain what is wrong int the code you shared ? Do you need the "transparent' portion of the bottom border to be at the center of the text link?

Comment: instead of solid try dashed

Comment: i am trying to have an animation that looks like the "transparent" portion is moving from left till the end of the text. Hope is more clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to understand that percent values for transforms are a portion of the element's bounding box (size), not of it's parent.
As the pseudo element is 35px wide, the transform moves it 35px. (*[see MDN for more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#formal_definition)*)

This said, you could use a border on the pseudo element for the "transparent" portion like this :

```css
body {
  background: #16263d;
}

a {
  font-size:20px;
  position:relative;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding:.2em 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}
a:after {
  content: '';
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-2px;
  right:100%;
  width:100%;
  height: 2px;
  border-right: 35px solid #16263d;
  transition: transform 0.75s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover:after {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Text Link and something more than this</a>
```

Comment: thanks for explanation and solution

Answer (score 0):

Try to use gradients:

```css
span {
 --g:40px; /* the gap */

 font-size:40px;
 background:
   linear-gradient(90deg,
      black   calc(50% - var(--g)/2),
      #0000 0 calc(50% + var(--g)/2), 
      black 0
   ) right bottom/calc(200% + var(--g)) 3px /* 3px = thickness */
   no-repeat;
}

span:hover {
  background-position: left bottom;
  transition:0.5s;
}
```

```html
<span>Some text</span>
```